# How does one create a child module?

Tags: perl

I've been out of the Perl world for way too long.  I want to create a child module and access its functions.  I'm basically just missing how to connect these and access the methods.

Parent example: WWW::Foo

```
package WWW::Foo
use strict;
use warnings;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw( new ) ] );
our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );
our @EXPORT = qw( );
our $VERSION = '0.01';

sub new {
    my ($package) = @_;

    $package::account_name = "Paul";
    return bless({}, $package);
}
```

Child example: WWW::Foo::Bar

```
package WWW::Foo::Bar
use strict;
use warnings;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw( new ) ] );
our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );
our @EXPORT = qw( );
our $VERSION = '0.01';

sub print_name {
    my ($package) = @_;
    # Access parent's package and do basic print.
    return;
}
```

Example Script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Foo;
use WWW::Foo::Bar;

my $foo = new WWW::Foo();
# Access WWW::Foo::Bar's print_name function
```

Comment: Exporting `new` makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: As I said I haven't been in the perl world for a long time, your comment is about as worthwhile as exporting new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short working example.

```
use strict;
package WWW::Foo;

sub new {
    my ($package) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $package;
    $self->{account_name} = "Paul";
    return $self;
}


package WWW::Foo::Bar;
use base "WWW::Foo";

sub print_name {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $name = $self->{account_name};
    print "Hello $name\n";
}


package main;
my $foo = WWW::Foo::Bar->new();
$foo->print_name();
```

Here is what has changed:

1. I've removed the use of `Exporter`. It is not necessary here -- all methods defined in a package can be called by name without its involvement.
2. The `new` method on `WWW::Foo` sets an `account_name` key on the object it's creating, rather than on the package itself. (Setting this on the package would mean that all objects had the same value here, making them rather useless.)
3. The `WWW::Foo::Bar` object now uses the `base` package to inherit from `WWW::Foo`.
4. The `WWW::Foo::Bar::print_name` method is now fleshed out. We can access the `account_name` key on the object to get the name. (This could also be written as a single line `print "Hello $self->{account_name}\n"`, but that would be less clear.)
5. The `main` package is declared. (This is just for simplicity. You don't need this if you're writing each package in its own file.)
6. We instantiate `WWW::Foo::Bar` rather than `WWW::Foo`, as we need the method that's defined on the child class. (If we instantiated the parent class `WWW::Foo`, it would not support this method.)
7. We don't use indirect method calls for `new`. Indirect method calls are bad.
8. We call `$foo->print_name()` to call the method.

Answer (score 4):

Your 'Child' example includes this line:

```
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw( new ) ] );
```

which will export a function called 'new' and won't export any other functions (e.g.: `print_name`).

However exporting functions is kind of 'old school' and something I almost never do in my Perl code any more.  In particular, if you're writing object oriented code (which you seem to be), you don't need to export anything, as the constructor will be called explicitly via the class name and all other methods are called via the object, so Perl know which package to find them in.

You're calling your constructor like this:

```
my $foo = new WWW::Foo();
```

It's considered better practice to avoid the 'indirect object syntax' and instead explicitly call new as a class method like this:

```
my $foo = WWW::Foo->new();
```

If you have been away from Perl for a while and want to do OO code, I'd really recommend taking a look at Moose.  [Moose::Manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual) a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing `use base` in your child class(`package WWW::Foo::Bar`)

```
use base qw(WWW::Foo);
```